# How to use VirtualBox guest controls with Microsoft Office?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, microsoft-office, guest-additions

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 with VirtualBox and a Windows XP VM. This VM has Office 2007 installed on it. How can I use Guest Controls so that Office files (`.docx`, `.xlsx`, `.pptx`, etc.) open in Office on the VM when launched from Linux?

Comment: What do you mean by "Guest Controls"? If, according to your tag "guest-additions", you are talking about the guest additions in your. VM. Does can not control how you open files on the host system.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this feature is not available in Virtual Box (at least I cannot find documentation relating to it.) It is available on other platforms, like Parallels on OSX and it's called [Shared Applications.](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/23692.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can do what you suggest, but it will require some finesse and bash scripting

- start by testing 'VBoxManage guestcontrol exec vmname winword.exe -arguments mydoc.doc' to make Word launch and open a document
- Once that is working, use VBoxmanage startvm "vmname" to start the vm if it isn't running
- Next, put them all together in a script with a commandline parameter that takes the filename as input
- Finally, create an action in gnome that allows you to right click and launch the bash script you wrote with the filename as a parameter.

Have fun!  Let us know what you come up with.